# What is an ImageObserver?

Tags: java, awt, bufferedimage, imageobserver

When you draw an image it requires an image observer. From what I understand so far a BufferedImage is an image observer. But my question is, what defines an image observer and what does it do? I'm quite confused.

Comment: How are you drawing your image? Could you please provide some code?

Comment: I'm using a BufferedImage so I'm just setting it to null, but since I came across it I wanted to find an explanation of what is does. I searched Google but couldn't find an explanation of what it is exactly.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First of all, `ImageObserver` is an **interface**. According to [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/ImageObserver.html):

> An asynchronous update interface for receiving notifications about Image information as the Image is constructed.

In other words, it's an object-oriented way to use Images which can be modified before fully created. Method `imageUpdate(Image img, int infoflags, int x, int y, int width, int height)` is called any time the image is modified. It returns `true` if it wants to be notified about further changes and `false` otherwise. This method can be used to force size, resolution, colours etc. It also gives you some control of the errors (`ERROR` flag). For more info see [this](http://doc.sumy.ua/prog/java/exp/ch17_02.htm).

The observer may also process important information about the image - for example if we're drawing an image on the screen and change it to a bigger one before the rendering is complete, there has to be a way to inform whatever we're drawing on that the dimension has changed (allocate more space) and that it has to deal with the changes. The fact that `ImageObserver` is *asynchronous* is extremely important in that case.

Answer (score 13):

`ImageObserver` is an interface that has methods for handling notification of state of image loading. It can use this for redisplay as needed.  `JFrame` and `Applet` both implement `ImageObserver` interface.

To keep users informed regarding the loading of *an* image

- `ImageObserver` interface – Enables the monitoring of the loading process so that 
  users can be informed and the image can be used asap once it is loaded.
- Loading an image asynchronously – how to know when the image is ready.

  - An image is ready – `getImage()` method returns, long before anything is 
    known about the image.

    ```
    imageUpdate(Image img, int infoflags, int x, int y, int width, int height)
    ```
- Note: `java.awt.Component` implements `ImageObserver`, all the subclasses do as 
  well!
- `g.drawImage(imge, 0,0, this)` -- this refers to the `ImageObserver` instance.
- `imageUpdate()` – Called by the `ImageObserver` whenever necessary. You do not call 
  it explicitly!

  - If the image is complete, returns `false`.
  - If the image is not complete and needs to be updated, returns `true`.
- `ImageObserver.ALLBITS = 32`
- Various constants are combined to form the `infoflags` argument, which indicates 
  whether all information is available or not.

  [image: info flag table]

Take a look at [this](http://cs.nyu.edu/~yap/classes/visual/03s/hw/h4/drawImage.pdf) and [Oreilly's explanation](http://oreilly.com/openbook/javawt/book/appd.pdf).